# how can i convert unicode type to str type?(maybe it isn't a matter of encode or decode)

Tags: python, unicode

I have a string `s` defined as:

```
s='中文'
```

I need to encode it as escaped code units (`\u4e2d\u6587`) like this:

```
s2='\u4e2d\u6587'
```

I tried this:

```
s1=unicode(s,'cp936') 
print type(s1)
```

But it prints `<type 'unicode'>` (where if I print `s` I get `<type 'str'>`).

If it matters I'm using Python 2.7.8.

Comment: `s` is not unicode; `s` is a bytestring, the way you posted it. Your `s2` line is invalid Python; please copy *actual python code* when showing us an example. Yes, to go from bytes to unicode you need to decode, but I'm not sure what actual question you have here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think op entered `s='中文'` in editor (in UTF-8 or whatever) and needs to make a unicode string from it with `s.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @myaut: but now we are second guessing here. We have no error output, no clear question.

Comment: @myaut: Adriano's interpretation *may* be correct, but I'd like to see confirmation from the OP. The community is free to reopen it with the normal voting procedure, of course. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: oh, I didn't notice that all text comments are came from Adriano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s='中文'` is a byte string in Python 2, so it is ambiguous what encoding the byte string is in.  It will be in the encoding of the source file, but that information is missing.

To make the conversion with a Unicode string, however, is straightforward:

```
>>> s = u'中文'
>>> type(s)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> b = s.encode('unicode_escape')
>>> b
'\\u4e2d\\u6587'
>>> type(b)
<type 'str'>
>>> print b
\u4e2d\u6587
```

Comment: @jaz, you're welcome.  On StackOverflow you may accept an answer to your question by selecting the check to the left of the answer.